# Trouble with install.packages() after update on Mac OSX snow leopard

Tags: macos, r

Earlier today I updated R to 2.14.2 so that I could install the new ggplot2. Now I'm getting the following error anytime I try and use install.packages():

```
Warning in install.packages :
package ‘foo’ is not available (for R version 2.14.2)
```

I've tried to rectify my mistake by removing R and installing an older version. I used the command:

```
rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/R.framework /Applications/R.app
```

Even after that reinstallation I got the same error (using 2.14.1 and 2.14.0).

Is this a problem anyone else is having on snow leopard?

Comment: What CRAN mirror are you using?

Comment: You should post this to the R-sig-mac mailing list.  Simon's very good about suggesting fixes or corrections to your installation.  My simple suggestion:  try using the tools inside the R.app to verify that you've got the packages on your system, or as Joshua said, that you've got a valid CRAN mirror specified in your configuration.

Comment: I usually use the USA (MD) mirror. But i've tried a few others around the world and all produce the same error. Also, I'm getting the error in Rstudio, the command line, and the Mac gui for R.app. I will post to R-sig-mac thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue tonight.
After reading your post and checking R-sig-mac, it appears that there was a sync problem to all the mirrors. In fact, the PACKAGE file for 2.14 for contributed packages on all these
mirrors are empty. 
Util this is fixed, you can try hit the master site by setting

```
repos = 'http://cran.r-project.org'
```

inside the install.packages() call.

I just tried and it works.

Kajia Yuan  (kajia.yuan@gmail.com)